# Obstacle avoidance using 2 fixed cameras on a robot

Tags: graphics, opencv, computer-vision, robotics

I will be start working on a robotics project which involves a mobile robot that has mounted 2 cameras (1.3 MP) fixed at a distance of 0.5m in between.I also have a few ultrasonic sensors, but they have only a 10 metter range and my enviroment is rather large (as an example, take a large warehouse with many pillars, boxes, walls .etc) .My main task is to identify obstacles and also find a roughly "best" route that the robot must take in order to navigate in a "rough" enviroment (the ground floor is not smooth at all). All the image processing is not made on the robot, but on a computer with NVIDIA GT425 2Gb Ram.

My questions are :

1. Should I mount the cameras on a rotative suport, so that they take pictures on a wider angle?
2. It is posible creating a reasonable 3D reconstruction based on only 2 views at such a small distance in between? If so, to what degree I can use this for obstacle avoidance and a best route construction?
3. If a roughly accurate 3D representation of the enviroment can be made, how can it be used as creating a map of the enviroment? (Consider the following example: the robot must sweep an fairly large area and it would be energy efficient if it would not go through the same place (or course) twice;however when a 3D reconstruction is made from one direction, how can it tell if it has already been there if it comes from the opposite direction  )

I have found this [response](http://mkoval.org/downloads/projects/igvc/igvc_design.pdf) on a similar question , but  I am still concerned with the accuracy of 3D reconstruction (for example a couple of boxes situated at 100m considering the small resolution and distance between the cameras).

I am just starting gathering information for this project, so if you haved worked on something similar please give me some guidelines (and some links:D) on how should I approach this specific task.

Thanks in advance,
Tamash

Comment: There's a reason DARPA has been doing grand challenges in this area.  It's not easy.

Comment: DARPA grand challenge vehicles have LIDAR, >4 cameras and dense GPS waypoints. And they still get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do obstacle avoidance, it is probably easiest to use the ultrasonic sensors. If the robot is moving at speeds suitable for a human environment then their range of 10m gives you ample time to stop the robot. Keep in mind that no system will guarantee that you don't accidentally hit something.

> (2) It is posible creating a reasonable 3D reconstruction based on only 2 views at such a small distance in between? If so, to what degree I can use this for obstacle avoidance and a best route construction?

Yes, this is possible. Have a look at ROS and their vSLAM. http://www.ros.org/wiki/vslam and http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping would be two of many possible resources.

> however when a 3D reconstruction is made from one direction, how can it tell if it has already been there if it comes from the opposite direction

Well, you are trying to find your position given a measurement and a map. That should be possible, and it wouldn't matter from which direction the map was created. However, there is the loop closure problem. Because you are creating a 3D map at the same time as you are trying to find your way around, you don't know whether you are at a new place or at a place you have seen before.

CONCLUSION
This is a difficult task!

Actually, it's more than one. First you have simple obstacle avoidance (i.e. `Don't drive into things.`). Then you want to do simultaneous localisation and mapping (SLAM, read Wikipedia on that) and finally you want to do path planning (i.e. sweeping the floor without covering area twice).

I hope that helps?

Comment: The SLAM link is pretty useful. The problem with ultrasonic sensors is that they offer a pretty small range (10/20 m or so) and I need to construct in some way, based on the landscape ahead , a "best route" in order to sweep as much as possible in the region(consider that I want to find some objects based on some electronic waves they are emmiting for a 10 m range in a vast region (1 square mile) so I must get to at least 10 m in order to detect it).

Comment: I understand the limitations of your ultrasonic sensors and I said, use US to do obstacle avoidance not for mapping!

Comment: Do you want to find ultrasonic beacons? Btw, what is your task? Get from A to B, or sweep the largest possible area, or build a complete map, or find certain objects?

Comment: Well I hope that this doesn't sounds funny but all of them. The area that I want to sweep has known coordinates (it's roughly a square rectangle of ~0.3 sq miles) but that is it. I must construct a 3d map of it send it back to a central server and also find a certain object (the finding of the object is no problem if I get to at least 10m of them). When the object is found the search ends. Getting from A to B is, for now, not the main problem. I only have 2 1.3 MP cameras and the region is pretty large and also indoors in a GPS-denied environment (the warehouse example).

Answer (score 1):

1. I'd say no if you mean each eye rotating independently.  You won't get the accuracy you need to do the stereo correspondence and make calibration a nightmare.  But if you want the whole "head" of the robot to pivot, then that may be doable.  But you should have some good encoders on the joints.
2. If you use ROS, there are some tools which help you turn the two stereo images into a 3d point cloud. http://www.ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc.  There is a tradeoff between your baseline (the distance between the cameras) and your resolution at different ranges.  large baseline = greater resolution at large distances, but it also has a large minimum distance.  I don't think i would expect more than a few centimeters of accuracy from a static stereo rig.  and this accuracy only gets worse when you compound there robot's location uncertainty.

   2.5. for mapping and obstacle avoidance the first thing i would try to do is segment out the ground plane.  the ground plane goes to mapping, and everything above is an obstacle.  check out PCL for some point cloud operating functions: http://pointclouds.org/
3. if you can't simply put a planar laser on the robot like a SICK or Hokuyo, then i might try to convert the 3d point cloud into a pseudo-laser-scan then use some off the shelf SLAM instead of trying to do visual slam.  i think you'll have better results.

Other thoughts:
now that the Microsoft Kinect has been released, it is usually easier (and cheaper) to simply use that to get a 3d point cloud instead of doing actual stereo.

This project sounds a lot like the DARPA LAGR program.  (learning applied to ground robots).  That program is over, but you may be able to track down papers published from it.